# Laptop keys not functioning

Tags: windows, keyboard

I am running windows 8.1 on my lenovo laptop. Of late, several keys on my laptop are not functioning properly. Some keys are getting stuck repeatedly, and some don't get registered at all.

I don't have linux installed. What I want to do is to see if my keyboard works properly on Linux. What's the easiest and most time efficient way to go about testing it?

Comment: It's unlikely the keys will work under Linux, it's probably a hardware problem. Google "linux live distribution" for distros you can boot from DVD or from an USB stick.

Comment: Did you remove the keys' software or anything like that in Windows? I usually only had such problems when removing their dedicated software, which seemed unnecessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @dirkt this was indeed a hardware problem. I had to eventually get the keyboard replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Download a Live-DVD  like [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.org/)